# strtok() doesn't process the second token

Tags: c

I want to get tokens from a string, then get sub-tokens of the tokens, like this short program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

void f(char *bak) 
{ 
    char *token, *delim = "."; 

    token = strtok(bak, delim); 
    while(token) { 
        printf("f(): token: %s\n", token); 
        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
    } 
} 

int main(void) 
{ 
    char str[] = "a.1.2 x.y"; 
    char *token, *delim = " \t\n\r"; 

    token = strtok(str, delim); 
    while(token) { 
        printf("main: token: %s\n", token); 

        char bak[100]; 
        strncpy(bak, token, sizeof(bak)); 
        f(bak); 

        token = strtok(NULL, delim); 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

However, it only shows the first token ("a.1.2"), not the second one:

```
main: token: a.1.2
f(): token: a
f(): token: 1
f(): token: 2
```

How did this happen? Thanks.

Comment: Use `const char *` for string literals. Even better, `std::string`.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok()` can only handle the tokenization of one string at a time (it depends on an internal static variable to maintain states between successive calls, non-reentrant and non-threadsafe).  The call to `strtok(bak, delim)` in `f()` invalidates the previous call to `strtok(str, delim)` in `main()`, so when the execution flow returns back to `main()` from `f()` and comes to the call to `strtok(NULL, delim)`, it's actually still working on the tokenization of `"a.1.2"` (which is already finished in `f()`), thus `token` is assigned with a null pointer value, which terminates the loop.

Comment: @user2847598: Yes, `strtok_r()` is the reentrant version of `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

strtok() handles one token for one string at a time. So, You can use strtok_r() function to handle multiple token at a time for one string.

SO, Its a recursive function of strtok() function.